# Why are my LEDs too dim in a chandelier

Tags: led, dimmer-switch, light-bulb

I bought 5 LEDs to put in a chandelier in my living room. However after I put them in I see that they’re far too dim. Here’s the weird part: replace any one of them with one of the old incandescent bulbs and their brightness shoots up. Why would this be?

Comment: Is it on a dimmer or just a plain switch?  LEDs can act weird on dimmers.

Comment: ...Or are old bulbs 25V bulbs wired in series? If one is out, do they all go out?